# why python-csv installation giving an error

Tags: python, csv, pip

**I tried to install a few packages for my project among all of them only python-csv is not getting installed and giving me an error**

`pip install python-csv` is giving me the following error

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in demjson setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

> i also tried to solve the problem by upgarding pip setup tools and ezsetup

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
ez-setup   0.9
pip        22.2.2
setuptools 65.3.0
```

but `pip install python-csv` is giving me the same error.

i.ve alse tried to install the package as admin it's still not working

[image]

can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

the issue was with the package itself the latest version of python-csv is geathering demjason2.2.4

```
pip install python-csv==0.0.10
```

but this one works perfectly and gathers demjason 3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, as my one file was called "csv.py", I changed the name and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-m pip install python-csv` or `!pip install python-csv`

Comment: not working showing the same error

Comment: I think you need to upgrade  your pip. First try `-m pip install --upgrade pip` and then do above code

Comment: current version of  pip is up todate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to move from [**`demjson`**](https://pypi.org/project/demjson/) (who seems to be abandoned) to [**`demjson3`**](https://pypi.org/project/demjson3/).

Run this :

```
pip unistall demjson
pip install demjson3
pip install python-csv
```

Comment: demjson2 is automatically being collected when i run pip install python-csv

Comment: Look at this https://github.com/jasontrigg0/python-csv/commit/347e71d77daf839809dd289b397402f1767e220f. I think you should open an issue here https://github.com/jasontrigg0/python-csv/issues